# Build swf using mxmlc (Ant) - Code compiles when code not changed

Tags: apache-flex, ant, mxmlc

I am using mxmlc task to generate swf for our project.
Problem is, even when I dont change any flex code, swf compiles every time, which is comparatively lengthy process.

Does anyone know how to avoid it? Is there any solution to this?

Thanks in advance,
Miral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Incremental compilation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ed3.html) should be what you are looking for. It's on by default when you compile from Flash Builder but not when you compile from the command line or Ant. The gist is that, with incremental compile on, mxmlc inspects your code looking for changes and only compiles what it needs to.

Comment: I tried with Command line ant build and it worked fine. It created *.swf.cache file for the first time and then take care itself.